# Uninstalling spyder

Tags: uninstall, spyder

I tried for some reason to uninstall Spyder (using purge --auto-remove and all) from Ubuntu 16.04. Apparently Spyder is now uninstalled, but

```
which spyder
```

gives

```
/usr/local/bin/spyder
```

and I can still launch Spyder.

How do I completely uninstall Spyder ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You have copies of this program not installed by your package manager.**

Have you installed packages from source or with other package managers such as pip? If you used something like pip, try uninstalling using pip. EG:

```
sudo pip uninstall spyder
```

If that doesn't work you can search your computer for spyder stuff, and delete it manually. Start by deleting spyder from /usr/local/bin:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/spyder
```

Now rerun `which spyder` and see if anything turns up. If so delete that too.

Finally, find and clean up any associated config files etc.

Locate is easy to use so install that first:

```
sudo apt install locate && sudo updatedb
```

Then look for spyder:

```
locate spyder
```

You can then look through the list that has been returned to you and decide if there is anything else you need to delete.

Comment: I honestly don't remember what I did to install Spyder on usr/local/bin but it was certainly me not understanding what I was doing. Anyways, I plainly deleted it and everything now seems uninstalled. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`pip uninstall spyder`

is only simply code to uninstall actually, I also got an identical error to uninstall so someone suggested I read [Syper Uninstallation](https://www.uninstallgeeks.com/uninstall-spyder)